# Exceeding memory limit in R (even with 24GB RAM)

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, dataframe

I am trying to merge two dataframes:  one has 908450 observations of 33 variables, and the other has 908450 observations of 2 variables.

```
dataframe2 <-merge(dataframe1, dataframe2, by="id")
```

I've cleared all other dataframes from working memory, and reset my memory limit (for a brand new desktop with 24 GB of RAM) using the code:

```
memory.limit(24576)
```

But, I'm still getting the error `Cannot allocate vector of size 173.Mb`.

Any thoughts on how to get around this problem?

Comment: package `data.table` can be more memory efficient and much much faster than `data.frames` since it makes fewer copies of data.

Comment: Are you actually using the 24 Gb, and related, is your os 64 bit?

Comment: The OS has to be able to allocate the require amount of contiguous memory to R. So you might be limited by other applications you have running.

Comment: @James Bingo.  Note it's not an R-specific problem, as the Stata docs advise to restart your computer before attempting a big merge.  That said, `data.table` is definitely the way to go for a dataset that big.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

To follow up on my comments, use `data.table`. I put together a quick example matching your data to illustrate:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:908450, matrix(rnorm(908450*32), ncol = 32))
dt2 <- data.table(id = 1:908450, rnorm(908450))
#set keys
setkey(dt1, id)
setkey(dt2, id)
#check dims
> dim(dt1)
[1] 908450     33
> dim(dt2)
[1] 908450      2
#merge together and check system time:
> system.time(dt3 <- dt1[dt2])
   user  system elapsed 
   0.43    0.03    0.47
```

So it took less than 1/2 second to merge together. I took a before and after screenshot watching my memory. Before the merge, I was using 3.4 gigs of ram. When I merged together, it jumped to 3.7 and leveled off. I think you'll be hard pressed to find something more memory or time efficient than that.

Before:
[image]

After:[image]

Comment: Hi there--Quick question.  I changed both of my dataframes into data tables using `dat1_table<-data.table(data1)` and `dat2_table<-data.table(data2)`.  But then, when I try to setkey, I get the error `Column 2 is length 9 which differs from length of column 1`. The number of rows appear to be the same using `dim()` however.

Comment: @roody - that is weird. I just tested using the examples above by making them data.frames first, then converting to data.tables using your method. I'm not able to reproduce the error. Are you sure that `data1` and `data2` are in fact data.frames? You can check with `class()`, or `str()` or `is.data.frame()`. You can also try setting the key when you make the data.table in one command, i.e. `dt <- data.table(yourDF, key = "yourKey")`

Comment: Hi Chase--Apparently a date-time variable in one of the datasets was mucking things up.  And it all worked! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: @roody - cool, glad you got it working. Here is some good background on [data.table](http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=packages:cran:data.table). It has a bit of a learning curve, but once you get up the curve - it quickly becomes invaluable for big data tasks. Lots of good resources here on SO as well.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can think of there's three solutions:

- Use datatables
- Use swap memory ( can be adjustable on *nix machines)
- Use sampling