# Memory limit when reading SPSS file

Tags: r, memory

I am having a memory issue while doing a very simple operation. I am trying to read an SPSS file (38Mb) with the read.spss function.

At first an error message popped up saying `cannot allocate vector of size 2 Mb`. Then I checked the memory limit

```
memory.limit()
[1] 16383
```

and increased it to

```
memory.limit(50000)
[1] 50000
```

When I retry reading the .sav file I get another error message saying `cannot allocate vector of size 1.5 Mb`. I am puzzled.... Has someone already encountered this problem?

Comment: This has come up once or twice!! Try searching with the R tag **[tag:r]** for `"cannot allocate vector of size"`...

Comment: Had that problem onces, rebooting R fixed it for me. But this is not realy an answer to your question, as I have no clue why.

Comment: Thank you both. @SimonO101 I carefully consulted the other answers before posting. I found that they mostly refer to computational problems that can be simplified by taking chunks instead of entire objects. I couldn't find specific answers to import problems. I am now learning that the `ff` package contains functions that write objects on disk instead than on memory but this is quite a new topic for me. If I find a way out, I'll edit my post to give more info on the problem and its solution.

Comment: You sure you looked "deep" enough? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564775/exceeding-memory-limit-in-r-even-with-24gb-ram?rq=1  would seem to cover your situation exactly.