# Join : Merging 2 dataframes with différents keys names

Tags: r

Hi I need to use join from plyr package to merge some data.frame

```
df1<-data.frame(var1=LETTERS[1:10],value1=sample(1:100,10))
df2<-data.frame(var2=LETTERS[1:10],value2=sample(1:100,10))
```

This is what I need

```
merge(df1,df2,by.x="var1",by.y="var2")
```

How can I do this With join from plyr pacakge

```
library(plyr)
join(df1,df2,by=c("var1","var2")) # no by.x or by.y option.. how can I do this WITHOUT renaming df1 or df2 ?
```

Regards

Comment: You can't. Just rename it. Or make a temporary `df3` that is a renamed version of `df2`.

Comment: You can't. It's really not a huge big deal. You could rename both columns to the same name for the sake of merging, then rename them back, if you really wanted to. Or just use same col name across the dfs.

Comment: mainly to appease my feeble mind, can you help me understand why you *need* to do something with package XYZ when you have a perfectly good solution listed out in your question?

Comment: @Chase the time : join is faster on big data frame.

Comment: @Bakalegum - fair enough. If speed / performance is a key concern, package `data.table` will probably be faster yet. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564775/exceeding-memory-limit-in-r-even-with-24gb-ram/11564999#11564999) for an example.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid saving a temporary dataset, in the `world` of `plyr` you could always do:

```
join(df1, rename(df2, replace=c("var2" = "var1")), by="var1")
```

, and borrowing from base R you could do:

```
join(df1, setNames(df2,c("var1",names(df2)[-1])), by="var1")
```

Comment: dplyr 0.3 is not working on this simple example. Regarding `dplyr` [news](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md), we should be able to `left_join` df2 on df1 with `by = c("var1" = "var2")`.

Comment: @PauloCardoso - this is for `plyr`, not `dplyr`. They are entirely different packages.

Comment: yes of course. just to comment that the same procedure should work with dplyr package but it won't.

Comment: @PauloCardoso - well, `join` and `rename` aren't even functions in `dplyr`, so it was never going to work.

Comment: @thelatemail - Thanks so much for this answer! It saved my bacon. With the R packages `magrittr` and `dplyr`, we can adapt your solution to a sequence of piped procedures. Roughly, your solution becomes `df1 %>% rename(var2 = var1) %>% join(df2, by="var2")`