# Merge multiple files in r

Tags: r, merge

I am trying to merge 2000 files of 2MB each into a single file. Each files has 2 columns of 100000 rows. Its a simple code though, but I am getting a error that reads:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 37.3 Gb

How do I solve this?

I am running a 64-bit R on 8GB RAM Windows 10. I have tried increasing the memory size to 50GB, but no use. Any suggestions please?

Here is my code: location is the variable that contains the path.

```
multmerge = function(mypath){ 
filenames=list.files(path=mypath, full.names=TRUE)
datalist = lapply(filenames, function(x){read.csv(file=x,header=T)}) 
Reduce(function(x,y) {merge(x,y)}, datalist)}
new_data<-multmerge(location)
```

Comment: what's your `memory.limit()` size?

Comment: Does this work if you run it on two of your files? What about 20? 100? 1000? Where does it crash? How big is the output data frame getting as you scale up? Maybe you need more RAM above the 8GB that the machine has? How much? Well, you don't know until you can find out how far the analysis can go.

Comment: Also, you might consider `mclapply` instead of `lapply` for such a task.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10917532) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11564775), simply there is not enough memory to process merge. Consider merging [outside R](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/113898)?

Comment: Have you considered storing the data in a SQLite database, for instance? See this related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29593177/manipulation-of-large-files-in-r/29593454#29593454

Comment: The number of columns in a `merge` of a two column matrix can *double* if the column names aren't right. You could be ending up with a matrix with zillions of columns. You've not given us any of your data nor shown chunks of it nor convinced us of its correctness. How can we help?

Comment: @AdamQuek: memory.limit() is 50GB.

Comment: @Spacedman: It worked perfect for 300 files, it doesn't work with 1500.

Comment: Edit your post to show us the first 10 lines of three or four of your files, and explain what output you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R memory management / cannot allocate vector of size n Mb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171593/r-memory-management-cannot-allocate-vector-of-size-n-mb)